# How international teams decide on jersey number?

Tags: football, fifa, uniform

On what basis jersey number will be given to players in their international teams if jersey number used in their leagues clashes? for example Torres and Villa share same jersey number 9 in Chelsea and Atletico Madrid respectively. Why it is given to Torres?

Comment: Likely the circumstances differ widely country to country and I doubt there is a single (or even small set) of correct answers here. Ask about a specific instance your interested in rather than in generalities please.

Comment: Usually there is no relation between the number they use in their team and the number their use in the international team.